# gulp cannot find module 'notify-send' on Laravel 5 Homestead

Tags: sass, gulp, laravel-5, homestead, laravel-elixir

I'm working with Laravel 5 (Elixir) and homestead v2.5 in Ubuntu 14.10. When I typed gulp and press enter in homestead ssh, I found the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/notifiers/notify-send'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/Code/rumta/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-notify/node_modules/node-notifier/index.js:2:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

What should I do to solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

Make new project and run sudo npm install.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `sudo` for that.  Your project files should never need to be owned by root.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me too with an unfinished previous installation.

A better solution I found was just removing **node_modules/** folder inside my project and run again `[sudo] npm install`.

Hope this helps somebody else, regards!

Update Note: **"sudo"** is not needed, a better practice is solve permissions issue in npm following [this guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Comment: This solution worked for me and is also recommended here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9204